# Spring boot application downloading JSP while hitting target, but not HTML

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-web

When I am hitting the URL it is downloading the JSP page but when I am using HTML page, it gets rendered in the browser. || HTML 1 - 0 JSP ||

Project structure

[image]

Application properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

Controller

[image]

It worked when I have added tomcat-embed-jasper dependency.
Why does that happened?

Comment: As JSP will get compiled to Servlet first and to run the servlet, we need a servlet enabled container. i.e. we need a container which can process the servlets and Tomcat is one of them. You can remove the embed tomcat and can run outside tomcat by building a war too....

Answer (score 1):

**- It worked when I have added tomcat-embed-jasper dependency. Why does that happened?**

Because it needs a webapp container.

Comment: As JSP will get compiled to Servlet first and to run the servlet, we need a servlet enabled container. i.e. we need a container which can process the servlets and Tomcat is one of them. You can remove the embed tomcat and can run outside tomcat by building a war too....

Answer (score 1):

I have came across with the same issue, file download every-time when i hit the Page. So, I have makes some changes & error has resolved.

1. Adding "tomcat-embed-jasper" in pom.xml file
2. having same version of your tomcat

   org.apache.tomcat.embed
           tomcat-embed-jasper
           9.0.68

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Embedded tomcat consider jsp rendering as optional. That's why it is needed.Also As I can understand. You must have provided scope of tomcat-embed-jasper dependency as provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below :

## DemoController.java :

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getLoginView(){
        return "login";  
    }       
    @GetMapping("/welcoome")
    public String welcome(){
        return "login";   
    }
}
```

## ApplicationConfigurerAdapter.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

## DemoApplication.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

## application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/
server.servlet.contextPath=/

server.port=6565
```

## pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You can build it as mvn package and can also run outside container(such as Tomcat)

[image: Project structure]
[image: Output]

Comment: I am using spring boot, and don't want to make a viewResolver

Comment: Not an issue . You can mention spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html

Comment: The problem is that I am able to render HTML pages but not JSP. doing this will allow spring to find *.html views only.

Comment: @AshutoshSharma extend your main class  from SpringBootServletInitializer and place EnableWebMvc annotation ....you can able to render JSPs too.. But yes, you need an servlet processing container

Answer (score 0):

Add this tomcat dependancy to your pom file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```